# Linking Facebook Proxygen with Cmake

Tags: c++, facebook, cmake, proxygen

Facebook's wangle library can be set up with cmake like below:

```
set_and_check(WANGLE_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/include/wangle)
set_and_check(WANGLE_CMAKE_DIR /usr/local/lib/cmake/wangle)

if (NOT TARGET wangle::wangle)
    include("${WANGLE_CMAKE_DIR}/wangle-targets.cmake")
endif()

set(WANGLE_LIBRARIES wangle::wangle)

if (NOT wangle_FIND_QUIETLY)
    message(STATUS "Found wangle: ${PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR}")
endif()
```

However, proxygen's install.sh doesn't put the include and lib files in /usr/local like wangle and other fb libraries do.

What is the proper way to set the include and link with proxygen via cmake?

Comment: The file you show is `wangle-config.cmake` config script which is **generated** (from [wangle/cmake/wangle-config.cmake.in](https://github.com/facebook/wangle/blob/master/wangle/cmake/wangle-config.cmake.in)) for a **specific** package installation. Other installations should come with their own `wangle-config.cmake` script. For use other installations you need to tell CMake to use corresponding script. You may do that e.g. by passing `-Dwangle_DIR=<dir-with-config-script>` parameter to `cmake`.

Comment: Recent version of proxygen install proxygen-config.cmake in /usr/local/lib/cmake and you can use it in your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: How do you make use of it in my CMakeLists.txt @AliShirvani

Answer (score 1):

According to the proxygen `README` you should install all requirements, including `folly`, `wangle`, `fmt`, `fizz`, and `mvfst` if you need HTTP/3 protocol. After installing proxygen with the instruction in the `README` you can use it in your CMake project. Following is an example `CMakeLists.txt` and you can find the complete sample project in [this repo](https://github.com/alishir/3hat).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(3hat)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

find_package(proxygen REQUIRED)
find_package(gflags REQUIRED)
  
add_subdirectory(server)
```

Comment: Never _ever_ set an absolute path in your CMakeLists.txt file and don't overwrite `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` there, either. You can _append_, however.

Comment: Can you give an example of how it should be done correctly @AlexReinking?
Also is it possible to link to proxygen without installing it?